# a constant sequence can iterate using for-in loop, but can't call next() directly?

Tags: swift, iterator, sequence, swift-protocols, for-in-loop

In the following code, `c` is a constant sequence (an instance of `Countdown`), it can iterate through its elements and break when the condition is met, and it can iterate from the start again.

But when I call `c.next()` directly, I get a compiler error: **cannot use mutating member on immutable value.**

So, I have two questions:

1. If I cannot call `c.next()`, why can it iterate through all the elements in the first place? Isn't it using the `next()` method internally to iterate through them?
2. In the second `for-in` loop in the following code, why is it not counting from `1` where the first iteration left off, instead it counts from the start, which is `3`?

```
struct Countdown: Sequence, IteratorProtocol { 
    // internal state
    var count: Int
    // IteratorProtocol requirement
    mutating func next() -> Int? {
        if count == 0 { return nil } else {
            defer { count -= 1 } 
            return count
        }
    }
}

// a constant sequence
let c = Countdown(count: 3)

// can iterate and break
for i in c { 
    print(i)              // 3, 2
    if i == 2 { break }
}

// iterate again from start (not from 1, why?)
for i in c { print(i) }   // 3, 2, 1

// ⛔️ Error: cannot use mutating member on immutable value.
//          `c` is a `let` constant.
c.next()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call `next` because `next` is `mutating`. `next` *changes the state of the iterator*, so that it "moves closer" to the end.

The `for` loop doesn't call `next` directly. It creates a *mutable* copy of `c` (`var`), and calls `next` on that:

```
// The for loop basically does this:
var copy = c // creates a copy
var element = copy.next()
element = copy.next()
element = copy.next()
...
```

The reason why the second for loop starts from the beginning is because of exactly this. `for` loops don't actually change the state of the thing you are iterating over. They create a copy, work with the copy, then throws it away.

One way to avoid this copying behaviour is to make `Countdown` a class:

```
class Countdown: Sequence, IteratorProtocol {
    // internal state
    var count: Int
    // IteratorProtocol requirement
    func next() -> Int? {
        if count == 0 { return nil } else {
            defer { count -= 1 }
            return count
        }
    }

    init(from n: Int){
        count = n
    }
}
```

Comment: `var copy = c // creates a copy` That's essentially what *actually* happens, except that it calls a default implementation of `makeIterator()`, which simply does `return self`, causing the copy. See the impl here: https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/1331ac594085a4a869822fbf729d80cc37abd0f0/stdlib/public/core/Sequence.swift#L381-L396

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica The note was there because for loops doesn't _always_ do that. it always calls `makeIterator`. But the point is, structs are copied. Maybe I should have worded my intention better...

Comment: Ah yes, indeed. This is a special-case of one of the many things `makeIterator` *can* do.

Comment: @Sweeper your class version of `Countdown` has the behavior I was originally expecting, kind of weird ^_^

Comment: @lochiwei The difference is that classes are reference types, so their values are not copied when you do an assignment such as `var copy = c`.

Comment: Now I have a clearer knowledge about the Swift `Sequence` protocol, thank you both.

Answer (score 2):

Because each `for` loop is creating a new iterator by calling the `makeIterator()` function of your sequence, which is defined by the standard library in a conditional expression of `Sequence`, but only when the conforming sequence also conforms to `IteratorProtcol`, as yours does.

Desugaring the `for` loops reveals the problem:

```
let c = Countdown(from: 3)

var iterator1 = c.makeIterator()
while let i = iterator1.next() { 
    print(i)              // 3, 2
    if i == 2 { break }
}

var iterator2 = c.makeIterator()
while let i = iterator2.next() { print(i) }   // 3, 2, 1
```

There are two separate iterators made, one per `for` loop. Each one "starts fresh" by virtue of originating from a copy of `c` (which has never been mutated).